# MySQL performance of querying json data

Tags: mysql, json

Compare the following 2 queries:

```sql
SELECT id,props->>"$.parent" AS parent FROM device WHERE props->>"$.parent"=0
```

and

```sql
SELECT id,props->>"$.parent" AS parent FROM device HAVING parent=0
```

Is there any difference in performance? `id` is the primary key and `props` is of type `json` and is **not** indexed.

Comment: *Is there any difference in performance?* No difference does this difference exists or not. Anycase you have no chance to detect it - if it exists, it is less then time measurement accuracy.

Comment: Did you try [profiling the queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-profile.html)?

Answer (score 0):

try running them both w/ explain to see.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT id,props->>"$.parent" AS parent FROM device WHERE props->>"$.parent"=0;

EXPLAIN
SELECT id,props->>"$.parent" AS parent FROM device HAVING parent=0
```

This should show you how the engine is going to try to execute them.

(Don't bother with PROFILE; I have yet to find any useful info in such.)

Comment: Profiling is different from explain. Explain only measures performance by giving you an estimate of the rows examined. It does not execute the query and give a timing. Profiling measures the time it takes to actually run the query, and breaks down the execution time to tell you which stage took the most time. E.g. temporary table creation.

Answer (score 0):

The Optimizer will probably move *that* Having clause into the Where clause.  To check for such:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...;
SHOW WARNINGS;
```

In which case, they are identical.

Otherwise, `HAVING` is always slower.

JSON should not be used for columns that are performance-critical. Use columns and INDEXing.  Probably `INDEX(parent)` is called for.